# Pandas method to back extend a time series by repeating the first value

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a method to extend a pandas time series into the past repeating the first value found in the serie?. For example:

```
serie = pd.Series(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index=pd.date_range("2022-01-01", "2022-01-05")
)
```

And I want an extended series

```
In [13]: extended_serie
Out[13]: 
2021-12-28    1
2021-12-29    1
2021-12-30    1
2021-12-31    1
2022-01-01    1
2022-01-02    2
2022-01-03    3
2022-01-04    4
2022-01-05    5
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

I'm asking if exists a direct method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `reindex` and `bfill` or use `fill_value` argument of `reindex` as mozway kindly pointing out.

```py
out = (serie.reindex(pd.date_range('2021-12-28', serie.index[0]).append(serie.index))
       .bfill())
# or
out = serie.reindex(pd.date_range('2021-12-28', serie.index[0]).append(serie.index), fill_value=serie.iloc[0])
```

```
print(out)

2021-12-28    1.0
2021-12-29    1.0
2021-12-30    1.0
2021-12-31    1.0
2022-01-01    1.0
2022-01-01    1.0
2022-01-02    2.0
2022-01-03    3.0
2022-01-04    4.0
2022-01-05    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: If only adding prior values, no need for `bfill`, use `fill_value=serie.iloc[0]` in `reindex` ;)

Comment: @mozway Thanks for pointing out that! Remember there is `fill_value` for `asfreq` but don't know this for `reindex`.

Comment: repeated `2022-01-01`

Comment: @Andrex That doesn't matter, if you don't want to generate last value in `pd.date_range`, use `inclusive='left'`.